# Multi-threaded Conway's Game of Life in C++ occasionally hitching?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml, conways-game-of-life

For practice I've implemented Conways' Game of Life in C++ with updates to the "world" being handled with parallel processing. I'm using [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) for graphics.

Adding multi-threading definitely made it run faster (at least on this 4-core machine) but I noticed it has issues. If I run it in a `Debug` configuration from Visual Studio 2017 it seems to start very slow, but after running for 2 seconds it suddenly gets faster and runs smoothly. But if I run it in `Release` configuration then it runs even faster than `Debug` did but every half a second or so it "hitches" or stutters and doesn't run smoothly like I expected.

What could be causing these two behavior issues and how can I fix them?

**GameOfLife.cpp:**

```
#include "GameOfLife.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class GameOfLife
{
public:
    GameOfLife(int sizeX, int sizeY);
    uint8_t & getCell(int x, int y);
    sf::Vector2i get2D(int i);
    void doUpdate(int start, int end);
    virtual ~GameOfLife() = default;
    void update();
    std::vector<sf::Vector2i> getLiveCells();

private:
    std::vector<uint8_t> world;
};

std::mutex updateListLock;
std::vector<sf::Vector2i> pendingUpdates;
sf::Vector2i worldSize;

GameOfLife::GameOfLife(int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    worldSize = sf::Vector2i(sizeX, sizeY);

    // initialize world to specified size, all starting as dead
    world = std::vector<uint8_t>(sizeX * sizeY, 0);

    // reserve space for worst case (every cell needs to be updated)
    pendingUpdates.reserve(sizeX * sizeY);

    // place a glider
    getCell(1, 3) = true;
    getCell(2, 4) = true;
    getCell(3, 2) = true;
    getCell(3, 3) = true;
    getCell(3, 4) = true;

    // place a glider at top-center
    int midX = std::floor(worldSize.x / 2);
    getCell(midX + 1, 3) = true;
    getCell(midX + 2, 4) = true;
    getCell(midX + 3, 2) = true;
    getCell(midX + 3, 3) = true;
    getCell(midX + 3, 4) = true;
}

uint8_t& GameOfLife::getCell(int x, int y)
{
    return world[y * worldSize.x + x];
}

sf::Vector2i GameOfLife::get2D(int index)
{
    int y = std::floor(index / worldSize.x);
    int x = index % worldSize.x;
    return sf::Vector2i(x, y);
}

// Update the cells from position start (inclusive) to position end (exclusive).
void GameOfLife::doUpdate(int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        auto pos = get2D(i);

        // # of alive neighbors
        int aliveCount = 0;

        // check all 8 surrounding neighbors
        for (int nX = -1; nX <= 1; nX++) // nX = -1, 0, 1
        {
            for (int nY = -1; nY <= 1; nY++) // nY = -1, 0, 1
            {
                // make sure to skip the current cell!
                if (nX == 0 && nY == 0)
                    continue;

                // wrap around to other side if neighbor would be outside world
                int newX = (nX + pos.x + worldSize.x) % worldSize.x;
                int newY = (nY + pos.y + worldSize.y) % worldSize.y;

                aliveCount += getCell(newX, newY);
            }
        }

        // Evaluate game rules on current cell
        switch (world[i]) // is current cell alive?
        {
        case true:
            if (aliveCount < 2 || aliveCount > 3)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(updateListLock);
                pendingUpdates.push_back(pos); // this cell will be toggled to dead
            }
            break;

        case false:
            if (aliveCount == 3)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(updateListLock);
                pendingUpdates.push_back(pos); // this cell will be toggled to alive
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

void GameOfLife::update()
{
    unsigned maxThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    // divide the grid into horizontal slices
    int chunkSize = (worldSize.x * worldSize.y) / maxThreads;

    // split the work into threads
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
    {
        int start = i * chunkSize;

        int end;
        if (i == maxThreads - 1) // if this is the last thread, endPos will be set to cover remaining "height"
            end = worldSize.x * worldSize.y;
        else
            end = (i + 1) * chunkSize;

        std::thread t([this, start, end] {
            this->doUpdate(start, end);
        });

        threads.push_back(std::move(t));
    }

    for (std::thread & t : threads) {
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }

    // apply updates to cell states
    for each (auto loc in pendingUpdates)
    {
        // toggle the dead/alive state of every cell with a pending update
        getCell(loc.x, loc.y) = !getCell(loc.x, loc.y);
    }

    // clear updates
    pendingUpdates.clear();
}

std::vector<sf::Vector2i> GameOfLife::getLiveCells()
{
    std::vector<sf::Vector2i> liveCells;
    liveCells.reserve(worldSize.x * worldSize.y); // reserve space for worst case (every cell is alive)

    for (int i = 0; i < worldSize.x * worldSize.y; i++) {
        auto pos = get2D(i);
        if (world[i])
            liveCells.push_back(sf::Vector2i(pos.x, pos.y));
    }

    return liveCells;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the performance issues are related to your code and not Visual Studio? If you have VS profiler on, or you load symbols, then it's not unexpected. What if you start the executable directly? Also. in each of your update calls, you create a bunch of threads which might slow your program down. Better keep a few threads only for updating -- but keep them alive all the time waiting on a queue or some kind of data structure to have update requests in it.
Also. If 2+ threads are editing cells that are close together, you will kill performance because of false sharing.

Comment: right now, every cell change requires acquiring a mutex which can cause a lot of contention. if instead each thread had its own update-list, the mutex wouldn't be needed at all

Comment: Aside: `for each (auto loc in pendingUpdates)` doesn't look like C++. Have you got something like `#define each` and `#define in :`? That sort of thing makes it *harder* for people experienced in C++ to look at your code

Comment: @Caleth: No macros, that's a Visual C++-ism.  Actually, Microsoft introduced ranged-for first, using this C#-like syntax, and then proposed it for standardization.  The Standardization committed changed the syntax when adopting it, to `for ( : )`.  Microsoft still supports their pre-Standard syntax to avoid breaking existing code.  Would be nice if `cl` generated a portability warning, though.

Comment: @Caleth that was a mistake, I should use the `for (int x : y)` syntax.

Comment: @AlexG I'm new to threading in C++, how do I keep threads alive?

Comment: @KyleV. You can look into [std::thread::detach](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach). Note that a detached thread will no longer be joinable, therefore it will live indefinitely unless you have your own mechanism to end it. What you could do is have a detached thread that waits until the main thread puts work in a task queue (or whatever structure). The wait can be implemented with a [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to multithread Game of Life, you should seriously consider double-buffering your `world` state. Then the threads are only *reading* shared state, and only one thread *writes* to any given location.

```
class GameOfLife
{
public:
    GameOfLife(sf::Vector2i size);
    void update();

private:
    void doUpdate(int start, int end);
    uint8_t& getCell(sf::Vector2i pos);
    sf::Vector2i getPos(int i);

    std::vector<uint8_t> world;
    std::vector<uint8_t> pendingWorld;
};

GameOfLife::GameOfLife(sf::Vector2i size)
  : worldSize(size), world(size.x * size.y, false), pendingWorld(world)
{
    // place a glider
    getCell({1, 3}) = true;
    getCell({2, 4}) = true;
    getCell({3, 2}) = true;
    getCell({3, 3}) = true;
    getCell({3, 4}) = true;

    // place a glider at top-center
    int midX = std::floor(worldSize.x / 2);
    getCell({midX + 1, 3}) = true;
    getCell({midX + 2, 4}) = true;
    getCell({midX + 3, 2}) = true;
    getCell({midX + 3, 3}) = true;
    getCell({midX + 3, 4}) = true;
}

uint8_t& GameOfLife::getCell(sf::Vector2i pos)
{
    return world[pos.y * worldSize.x + pos.x];
}

sf::Vector2i GameOfLife::get2D(int index)
{
    int y = index / worldSize.x;
    int x = index % worldSize.x;
    return { x, y };
}

// Update the cells from position start (inclusive) to position end (exclusive).
void GameOfLife::doUpdate(int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        auto pos = get2D(i);

        // # of alive neighbors
        int aliveCount = 0;

        // check all 8 surrounding neighbors
        for (sf::Vector2i dp : { {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, -1}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1} })
        {
            auto np = pos + dp;    
            // wrap around to other side if neighbor would be outside world
            np.x %= worldSize.x;
            np.y %= worldSize.y;

            aliveCount += getCell(np);
        }

        // Evaluate game rules on current cell
        bool stays = aliveCount == 2 || aliveCount == 3;
        bool spawns = aliveCount == 3
        pendingWorld[i] = world[i] ? stays : spawns;
    }
}

void GameOfLife::update()
{
    unsigned maxThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    // divide the grid into horizontal slices
    int chunkSize = world.size() / maxThreads;

    // split the work into threads
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
    {
        int start = i * chunkSize;
        int end = std::min(world.size(), (i + 1) * chunksize);

        threads.emplace_back(&GameOfLife::doUpdate, this, start, end);
    }

    for (std::thread & t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

    // apply updates
    world.swap(pendingWorld);
}
```

If you have a C++17 compiler, I would avoid explicit threads, write `doUpdate` in terms of a single index, and call `std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [this](int i) { doUpdate(i); });`

Comment: I noticed you got rid of `if (t.joinable())` did I not need that? Aside from that, if I understand correctly your main change was to double-buffer the world so that I don't need the mutex anymore, am I right?

Comment: @KyleV. it is impossible for `joinable()` to return false in this instance. It will only return false when the thread has not been started or `join` has already been called

Comment: @KyleV. Yes, the main change is letting there be a single `world.swap(pendingWorld);` outside of the threaded work

Comment: @Caleth I forgot to ask, what would be an alternative to using `std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [this](int i) { doUpdate(i); });` if I'm in a C++ 11 code base?

Comment: @KyleV. You'd write something like what you already wrote, dividing the process into chunks and running multiple threads. The C++17 parallel overloads just automatically do that